# Java code - Best way to list java processes in localhost JVM (for Linux & Windows]

Tags: java, java-8, process, console-application

I'm writing a console app that will run in Linux and Windows systems. This app will mainly run on JRE 1.8 environments.

In my code, it needs to get a list of Java processes that run on the host running my application. I have read the posts about jps, which come as a part of JDK, but not JRE, and also it's a separate executable.

My question is, is there any java library that I can use, to list (and ideally also kill some of) the running Java processes? Preferably, I would not want to hassle of calling jps executable with sth like Runtime.exec().

Thanks in advance, for any suggestions.

Comment: The [Attach API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/jdk.attach/module-summary.html) is your friend. It also exists in Java 8 when you include the `tools.jar` of your JDK into your classpath. That implies that it still requires a JDK though.

Comment: Thanks @Holger for the suggestion, but I would like to see if other options are possible than needing an entire JDK for this "simple" need. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the 3rd party library named Oshi, which apparently does not need JDK and is compatible with Java 1.8: https://github.com/oshi/oshi

For future reference, here is a sample method:

```
public static List<OSProcess> getOSProcesses() {
    SystemInfo si = new SystemInfo();
    OperatingSystem os = si.getOperatingSystem();
    return os.getProcesses();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Oops: I just spotted that you need solutions for JRE1.8, this will only help for JRE9+.

A simple way to scan processes within JRE is to use `ProcessHandle.allProcesses()`. This will read all processes and you can add filter on simple name match with "java" or "java.exe":

```
Path java = Path.of("bin", "java.exe");  // use "java" if not on Windows

ProcessHandle.allProcesses()
             .filter(ph -> ph.info().command().isPresent())
             .filter(ph -> Path.of(ph.info().command().get()).endsWith(java))
             .forEach(ph -> {
                 System.out.println("PID "+ph.pid()+" "+ph.info().command());
})
```

This approach won't spot Java VMs embedded in EXE - such as from `jpackage` - so is not as reliable as using JDK `jps` which does recognise `jpackage` EXEs and JDK tools like `jshell.exe`.

Comment: Well, this is not the answer I'm looking for, but I just wanted to upvote for reminding to be careful about the name of the process to filter, especially if I consider using a packaging tool like jpackage.. I'm still searching for the answer for my particular need.

Comment: You don’t need to embed the JVM into another EXE to make this fail, just using `javaw.exe` would be enough. Besides that, all the JDK tools, e.g. `javac` are in fact alternative launchers for programs written in Java.